# Shallow Test of React Component With React Router V4

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am attempting to do a shallow test of my React Login Component with Jest + Enzyme, but am running into issues with React Router V4. When the test is run, I get an error from Jest claiming:

```
cannot read property push of undefined.
```

Here is my test, and below that, is the method inside my component that is being tested.

```
describe('Login Component', () => {
  let wrapper
  const mockSignInFunc = jest.fn()

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Login signIn={mockSignInFunc} />)
  })

  it('renders itself', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('.login').length).toEqual(1)
  })

  it('should call the signIn function on submittal', () => {
    wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit', { preventDefault() {}})
    expect(mockSignInFunc.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe(1)
  })

}) // end describe block
```

Method being tested:

```
handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  this.props.signIn()
  this.props.history.push('/') // fails here
}
```

If I remove the this.props.history.push('/') line of code, the test passes, so I know it is a React Router problem. I tried to read some other documentation on this, where wrapping your component in a MemoryRouter is supposed to work, but per usual, the React Router docs leave plenty to be desired.

I am actually using HashRouter in my app, and am not sure if using a MemoryRouter is just a hack to get it to work. Beats me.

Does anyone know how I can get this test to pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're testing behaviour. You expect the history prop to be called with some value, so you need to mock it and pass it to your component.

```
const history = {push:jest.fn()}
```

And check if it is called

Comment: I tried const mockHistory = jest.fn() and did wrapper = shallow(<Login signIn={mockSignInFunc} history={mockHistory} /> and it just says that this.history.props.push is not a function. Still fails.

Comment: That allows it to pass. I did not want to test whether react router was being called anyways, all I was looking for was to see if my signIn method is called. I changed the expect to this, along with your code you suggested, expect(mockSignInFunc.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)

Comment: Please use expect(mockSignInFunc).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

Comment: Cool. This works. I changed it to toHaveBeenCalledTimes. Thanks for the tip.